# JBundler downloads jars, then says it can't find them

Tags: maven, jruby, jclouds

I'm writing a JRuby on Rails applications that uses JBundler to pull in jclouds jars from a Maven repository. It first downloads them and then says it can't find them.

Here is my Jarfile:

```
repository :apache_snapshots, "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

jar "org.apache.jclouds:jclouds-all",           "1.6.3-SNAPSHOT"
jar "org.apache.jclouds.driver:jclouds-sshj",   "1.6.3-SNAPSHOT"
jar "org.apache.jclouds.driver:jclouds-log4j",  "1.6.3-SNAPSHOT"
```

I run JBundler:

```
jruby -S jbundle install
```

First it pulls in the gems:

```
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.1)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.1)
Using mime-types (1.25)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.1)
Using activemodel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord (4.0.1)
Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.3)
Using jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2.1)
Using activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.3.3)
Using backports (3.3.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.1)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using descendants_tracker (0.0.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using haml (4.0.4)
Using haml-rails (0.4)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.5.2)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using virtus (0.5.5)
Using maven-tools (0.33.5)
Using ruby-maven-libs (3.1.0)
Using ruby-maven (3.1.0.0.1)
Using jbundler (0.5.3)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using jquery-datatables-rails (1.11.2)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.0)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.1)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using sass (3.2.12)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4)
Using therubyrhino (2.0.2)
Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
Using uglifier (2.3.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

The it finds the the jars:

```
downloading http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/rackspace-cloudidentity/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/rackspace-cloudi
dentity-1.6.3-20131114.121954-46.pom
downloaded http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/rackspace-cloudidentity/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/rackspace-cloudid
entity-1.6.3-20131114.121954-46.pom
artifact descriptor missing: org.apache.jclouds.api:rackspace-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46
downloading http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/openstack-keystone/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/openstack-keystone-1.
6.3-20131114.121702-46.pom
downloaded http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/openstack-keystone/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/openstack-keystone-1.6
.3-20131114.121702-46.pom
artifact descriptor missing: org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-keystone:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121702-46
downloading http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/openstack-cinder/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/openstack-cinder-1.6.3-
20131114.121804-46.pom
downloaded http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/openstack-cinder/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/openstack-cinder-1.6.3-2
0131114.121804-46.pom
artifact descriptor missing: org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-cinder:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121804-46
downloading http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/rackspace-clouddns/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/rackspace-clouddns-1.
6.3-20131114.122048-46.pom
downloaded http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/rackspace-clouddns/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/rackspace-clouddns-1.6
.3-20131114.122048-46.pom
artifact descriptor missing: org.apache.jclouds.api:rackspace-clouddns:jar:1.6.3-20131114.122048-46
downloading http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/provider/aws-cloudwatch/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/aws-cloudwatch-1.6.3
-20131114.122345-45.pom
downloaded http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/provider/aws-cloudwatch/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/aws-cloudwatch-1.6.3-
20131114.122345-45.pom
artifact descriptor missing: org.apache.jclouds.provider:aws-cloudwatch:jar:1.6.3-20131114.122345-45
downloading http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/cloudwatch/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/cloudwatch-1.6.3-20131114.121
126-46.pom
downloaded http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jclouds/api/cloudwatch/1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/cloudwatch-1.6.3-20131114.1211
26-46.pom
artifact descriptor missing: org.apache.jclouds.api:cloudwatch:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121126-46
...
...
```

Then it fails to find them:

```
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.j
clouds.api:rackspace-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-keystone:jar:1.6.3-201
31114.121702-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-cinder:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121804-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:rackspace-
clouddns:jar:1.6.3-20131114.122048-46, org.apache.jclouds.provider:aws-cloudwatch:jar:1.6.3-20131114.122345-45, org.apac
he.jclouds.api:cloudwatch:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121126-46, org.apache.jclouds.provider:rackspace-cloudblockstorage-us:jar:1
.6.3-20131114.123111-45, 
...
: Could not find artifact org.apache.jclouds.api:ra
ckspace-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46 in central (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384
)
        at jbundler.Aether.resolve(Aether.java:236)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:837)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2722)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:959)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:573)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.requireCommon(LoadService.java:457)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:421)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1088)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require19(RubyKernel.java:1082)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require19.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require19.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_3DF639EECD034ECD6A4437F10F83634659C9A8652454845.chained_2_ensure_2$RUBY$__ensure__(c:
/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_3DF639EECD034ECD6A4437F10F83634659C9A8652454845.chained_1_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__fi
le__(c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_3DF639EECD034ECD6A4437F10F83634659C9A8652454845.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(c:
/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_3DF639EECD034ECD6A4437F10F83634659C9A8652454845.__file__(c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shar
ed/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_3DF639EECD034ECD6A4437F10F83634659C9A8652454845.__file__(c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shar
ed/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_with_backports_3FA1B7F6257465E5D2C45E2C13998C417D0E279F2454845.chained_0_rescue_1$RUB
Y$SYNTHETIC__file__(c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_with_backports_3FA1B7F6257465E5D2C45E2C13998C417D0E279F2454845.__file__(c:/jruby-1.7.
6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:327)
        at rubyjit.Kernel$$require_with_backports_3FA1B7F6257465E5D2C45E2C13998C417D0E279F2454845.__file__(c:/jruby-1.7.
6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:201)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send19(RubyBasicObject.java:1504)
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$send19.call(RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$send19.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgNode.java:67)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgNode.java:69)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:126)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:173)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
        at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:837)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2722)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66)
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.load(LoadService.java:359)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loadCommon(RubyKernel.java:1109)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load19(RubyKernel.java:1101)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load19.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load19.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
        at c_3a_.jruby_minus_1_dot_7_dot_6.bin.jbundle.__file__(c:/jruby-1.7.6/bin/jbundle:23)
        at c_3a_.jruby_minus_1_dot_7_dot_6.bin.jbundle.load(c:/jruby-1.7.6/bin/jbundle)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:810)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:803)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:672)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:521)
        at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:395)
        at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:290)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:217)
        at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:197)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org
.apache.jclouds.api:rackspace-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-keystone:jar:
1.6.3-20131114.121702-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-cinder:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121804-46,
...
: Could not find artifact org.apache.jclou
ds.api:rackspace-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46 in central (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367
)
        ... 154 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.jclouds.api:rackspa
ce-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46 in central (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
NativeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resol
ved: org.apache.jclouds.api:rackspace-cloudidentity:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121954-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-keyst
one:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121702-46, org.apache.jclouds.api:openstack-cinder:jar:1.6.3-20131114.121804-46,
 ...
 in central (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2)
     resolveDependencies at org/eclipse/aether/internal/impl/DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384
                 resolve at jbundler/Aether.java:236
                 resolve at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jbundler-0.5.3/lib/jbundler/aether.rb:94
                  (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jbundler-0.5.3/lib/jbundler.rb:42
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1082
                 require at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
                 require at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
                 require at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53
                 require at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53
  require_with_backports at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328
  require_with_backports at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328
                  (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jbundler-0.5.3/lib/jbundler/cli.rb:1
                 install at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jbundler-0.5.3/lib/jbundler/cli.rb:71
                     run at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27
             invoke_task at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb
:120
                dispatch at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344
                   start at c:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434
                    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101
                  (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.6/bin/jbundle:23
                  (root) at c_3a_/jruby_minus_1_dot_7_dot_6/bin/c:/jruby-1.7.6/bin/jbundle:23
```

How can I make JBundler realize that it's already found the gems that it's looking for?

Alternately, is there an alternative to JBundler which is known to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix things by switching from [JBundler](https://github.com/mkristian/jbundler) to [lock_jar](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar).

I also had to downgrade one of the packages to a version available in the main Maven repository. Lock_jar couldn't find it in the Apache snapshots repository, but it gave a much friendlier error message.

New jarfile in the lock_jar format:

```
repository "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

jar "org.apache.jclouds:jclouds-all:1.6.3-SNAPSHOT"
jar "org.apache.jclouds.driver:jclouds-sshj:1.6.2-incubating"
jar "org.apache.jclouds.driver:jclouds-log4j:1.6.3-SNAPSHOT"
```